# How youtube decides the width and height of generated the iframe code?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm making a feature that exposes iframe code for our users can use it to embed the video on their sites and want to do it as youtube does.

The problem is most of the time the size of the iframe that youtube generates for me is 560x315. But sometimes, it is 1280x720. So how youtube decides the size of the iframe that will be generated? Depend on the resolution or screen size or something.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you embed a youtube iframe the default size is 560*315, however, you can modify that by changing the width and height of the iframe tag.

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720"></iframe>
```

Comment: That is not what I meant to ask. My question is sometimes the size that youtube gave me is 560x315, another time is 1280x720. So what are the factors that youtube's developers take into account when deciding the size of the iframe they generate?